# Logging messages to Redis with monolog is not working

Tags: symfony, redis, monolog

I want to log messages to a local Redis server with Monolog in a Symfony 2 project. I'm using the [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle) for this purpose.

This should be straight forward following the documentation, but it seems that no messages are stored in Redis. If I use the the default Redis client configured and write something to the Redis server this works perfectly.

My configuration is the following:

```
snc_redis:
  clients:
    default:
        type: predis
        alias: default
        dsn: redis://localhost
    monolog:
        type: predis
        alias: monolog
        dsn: redis://localhost/1
        logging: false
        options:
            connection_persistent: true
  monolog:
    client: monolog
    key: monolog

monolog:
  handlers:
    custom:
        type:  service
        id:    snc_redis.monolog.handler
        level: debug
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I added the configuration code

Comment: try changing your handler 'custom' to 'main'

Comment: @guy_fawkes that does not make a difference sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to watch out for the fact that monolog handlers are redefined in config_prod.yml and config_dev.yml, so if you define them in config.yml they will just be overwritten by the prod or dev config. I'm not sure where you did it but if you have the redis and monolog configs together it is a probable cause that you just configured monolog in the wrong file.

Comment: I did configure them in the config_dev.yml so this should be correct.

Comment: OK strange, then I'm not quite sure what's up sorry. Maybe report it on github on snc's repository.